# Crop and resize image with jQuery cropit

Tags: jquery, image, crop, profile

I'm trying to create a profile photo upload and crop using the jQuery plugin [cropit](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/).

This is my markup:

```
  <form action="#">
    <div class="image-editor">
      <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
      <div class="image-size-label"> Resize image </div>
      <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
      <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
      <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

My question is how to load and crop an existing image like in the [first demo](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/).

Comment: ...doesn't the demo come with source code? Why does it not work for you?

Comment: No there's no demo using existing image.I tried inspecting the thtat demo page and found that image is loaded as back ground.I tried to load the existing image as background image of ".cropit-image-preview".But the cropping is not working.

Comment: It gives *explicit instructions* on how to use an image: `// In the demos I'm passing in an imageState option
// so it renders an image by default:
// $('#image-cropper').cropit({ imageState: { src: { imageSrc } } });`

Comment: @Juhana Oopz, My bad.I read the docs many times and didn't see it.Anyway thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is an example:

My Demo might not work in here but its working fine in my local environment.So keep trying.

You can also see [example](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Image-Zoom-Pan-Crop-Plugin-Cropit.html)

You can download demo [here](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit)

```js
  $(function() {
        $('.image-editor').cropit({
          imageState: {
            src: 'http://lorempixel.com/500/400/',            
            //src: 'your_image_path/to_be_crop_image.jpg',
          },
        });

        $('.export').click(function() {
          var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
          window.open(imageData);
        });
  });
```

```css
      .cropit-image-preview {
        background-color: #f8f8f8;
        background-size: cover;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 3px;
        margin-top: 7px;
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        cursor: move;
      }

      .cropit-image-background {
        opacity: .2;
        cursor: auto;
      }

      .image-size-label {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      input {
        display: block;
      }

      .export {
        margin-top: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="http://uttamkumarroy.com/jquery.cropit.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-editor">
      <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
      <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
      <div class="image-size-label">
        Resize image
      </div>
      <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
      <button class="export">Export</button>
    </div>
```

Thanks